# run Pylint from python using subprocess: Error 30

Tags: python, pylint

I try to run Pylint from Python script using the library "subprocess"; however, I always receive the following error:

> Command '['pylint', 'E:\python_projects\machine_learning_projects\alibi\', '--recursive=True']' returned non-zero exit status 30.

The source code is:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import subprocess

def pylint_project(project_path):

    if not os.path.exists(project_path):
        raise ValueError("Path not valid.")
        output = subprocess.check_output(['pylint', project_path, "--recursive=True"]).decode('utf-8')
        rating = output.split('Your code has been rated at ')[1].split('/')[0]
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        rating = None
    df = pd.DataFrame({'project': [os.path.basename(project_path)], 'rating': [rating]})

    return df

path = "E:\python_projects\machine_learning_projects\\alibi\\"
print(pylint_project(path))
```

I tried to run the same command using the CMD without errors (I suppose that always is correctly installed)

The Operative System that I'm using is "Windows 11".

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `subprocess` for that, pylint has an API:

```
from pylint import run_pylint

run_pylint(argv=[project_path, "--recursive=True"])
```

See https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development_guide/api/pylint.html

Answer (score 1):

Thats how pylint works. If it detects warnings/errors, it will return a bitmapped exit code of *non-zero* value to indicate what sort of things it detected.

Now, you are using `subprocess.check_output()` - on its documentation, following is said:

> **If the return code was non-zero it raises a CalledProcessError.** The CalledProcessError object will have the return code in the returncode attribute and any output in the output attribute.

(emphasis mine)

If you do `pylint --help`, you will see following:

```
  --exit-zero           Always return a 0 (non-error) status code, even if
                        lint errors are found. This is primarily useful in
                        continuous integration scripts. (default: False)
```

So, add `--exit-zero` to your arguments passed to pylint or add exception handling for `CalledProcessError` or switch to `subprocess.run()` ?